# Is there a quota for each IP address and is there anything we can do about it?

Tags: pagespeed-insights, psi, google-pagespeed-insights-api

we pull data for a lot of customers via the API. Each person uses their own key, but we pull the data from our IPs.

We recently reduced the number of IP addresses used for this and it has lead to a lot of "quota exceeded" messages. We're not exceeding any individual quotas and it only happened after we dropped hundreds of IP addresses, so we believe there is some quota per IP that's not specified. We're wonder what, if anything we can do about this?

Example message received (redacted URL):

`[2023-06-19T02:41:12.6561] 463744: [site_audit.worker:warn] query_gapi_psi: api_error url=https://example.com/page. (Gapi_common.E_Request    {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"rateLimitExceeded","message":"Quota exceeded. Please wait a while and try again."}],"code":429,"message":"Quota exceeded. Please wait a while and try again."}})`